# The best way to find the starting index of each occurrence of a duplicate word in a string with javaScript

Tags: javascript

findIndexes(s,kw) is supposed to find the starting index of each occurrence of a keyword(kw) in a string(s).

```
function findIndexes(s,kw){
    var result = [];
    s = " " + s.toLowerCase() + " ";
    kw = " " + kw.toLowerCase() + " ";  
    var i = s.indexOf(kw);

    while (i >= 0){
        result.push(i);
        i = s.indexOf(kw, i+kw.length);
    };

    console.log("The index of " + kw +":");
    for (var i =0; i < result.length; i++)
    console.log(result[i]);
}

findIndexes("Apple PEAR banana pineapple STRAWBERRY appLE CrabApple ApPle","apple");
// returns 0, 39, 55
```

This is the best I could get it working but I don't like that I have to put space before and after both string set (`s = " " + s.toLowerCase() + " "; kw = " " + kw.toLowerCase() + " ";`) to exclude those words contain the search word (pineapple,ect...).I tried to use   RegExp (`kw = new RegExp('\\b'  + kw + '\\b');` but then it is not working. I would appreciate if you can come up with a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.prototype.split` to split your string by `" "`  and obtain the words this way, then check the elements against the key you are looking for.

```
function getIndexes (str,key) {
  var up="toUpperCase",result = [];
      str=str.split (" ");
      str.unshift(0);      
  str.reduce (function (index,word) {
    if (key[up]() === word[up]())
      result.push(index);
    return index + word.length + 1;
  });
  return result;
}

console.log (
  getIndexes (
  "Apple PEAR banana pineapple STRAWBERRY appLE CrabApple ApPle","apple"
  )
); //[0, 39, 55]
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/idIcopu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

The [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) does not work with regexes, you would need to use the [`search` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to find a match index. However, to make multiple matches you need to [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) the regex:

```
function findIndexes(s,kw){
    var result = [],
        kw = new RegExp('\\b' + kw + '\\b', 'ig'),
//         case insensitive and global flags ^^
        r;
    while (r = kw.exec(s)) {
        result.push(r.index);
    }

    console.log.apply(console, result);
    return result;
}
```